# Making a Button to move an object

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I am making an A-Frame site and I need to create a button to move a ball with the id:"test" to it's starting position: 0 8 0. I've tried with the setAttribute script and it doesn't work. This is the javascript code I'm currently working with:

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('ballreset', {
  events: {
    click: function(evt)
    {
      document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('position', {x:0, y:8, z:0});
      
    }
  }
});
```

*Edit: I found a typo in the code. But didn't solve problem*

Comment: setAttribute accepts string values, try to use document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('position', '0 8 0');

Comment: No. That didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a full example its hard to tell what exactly is the problem but,

- make sure you do have a raycaster - based [cursor component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.1.0/components/cursor.html#sidebar). Mouse clicks won't work with webGL renders like they do with HTML elements.
- make sure the click listener is working, ie. by logging each click
- make sure the element with the given `id` exists at the time of the click

Below is a working version of something similar to what you want to achieve (click any object):

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
    events: {
      click: function(evt) {
        // grab the current position
        let pos = this.el.getAttribute("position");
        // move upwards
        this.el.setAttribute('position', { x: pos.x, y: pos.y + 0.25, z: pos.z });
      }
    }
  });
</script>
<!-- attach a cursor component -->
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" foo></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" foo></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D" foo></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" foo></a-plane>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: I'll take this into account and have the ball return to the user for them to click and return. This might make it less complex.